# SignedXml reports "Unknown transform has been encountered."

Tags: c#, .net, xml, sign, xml-signature

I need to verify a signed xml.

When running in c# the next error appears: "Unknown transform has been encountered.". However running in java it correctly validates the xml.

It looks like the the xmldsig-filter2 is not recognized by .net framework. Could anything be done on this matter in c#/.net?

```
<dsig:Signature xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <dsig:SignedInfo>
    <dsig:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    <dsig:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
    <dsig:Reference Id="reference-data-0" URI="">
      <dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2">
          <xf2:XPath Filter="intersect" xmlns:xf2="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2">here()/ancestor::SomeNS:SomeElement[1]</xf2:XPath>
        </dsig:Transform>
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
      </dsig:Transforms>
      <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
      <dsig:DigestValue>...</dsig:DigestValue>
    </dsig:Reference>
  </dsig:SignedInfo>
  <dsig:SignatureValue>
    ...
  </dsig:SignatureValue>
</dsig:Signature>
```

Comment: Is there any solution to this? I would REALLY like to avoid stuffing IKVM to my project.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive from the `Transform` class and implement the algorithm yourself and register the transform using `CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm`. But .NET does not allow transform to be safe for canoicalization so you must allow it in the [registry](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Security/system/security/cryptography/xml/signedxml.cs,170d5794199945e8) under `HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\Security\SafeTransformMethods` or use reflection to modify the private field holding the list.

```cs
public class XmlDigSigFilter2Transform : Transform {
  public static void Register() {
    var self = CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(Url);
    if (self == null) {
      CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(XmlDigSigFilter2Transform), Url);
    }
    var signedXmlType = typeof(SignedXml);
    var knownCanonicalizationMethodsField =
      signedXmlType.GetField(
        "s_knownCanonicalizationMethods",
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

    if (knownCanonicalizationMethodsField == null) {
      return;
    }

    var knownCanonicalizationMethodsValue =
      knownCanonicalizationMethodsField.GetValue(new SignedXml());

    if (!(knownCanonicalizationMethodsValue is IList<string> list)) {
      return;
    }

    if (!list.Contains(Url)) {
      list.Add(Url);
    }
  }

 ...
}
```